# Check for array length of 1 fails every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build page specific menues.

Each menu can have sub links up to level three, each link can contain 0 to many sub-links. My logic for handling this is:

```
If a subLink array has length of 1 
 Run link component
Else if subLink array length greater than 1 
 Run map and the link component inside the map
```

How ever my test for subLink.length = 1 fails every time, so I cannot render anything with an array length of 1.

Here is my component:

```
const LevelTwo = (props) => {
  const input = props.props;
  console.log("Input is ===========================", input);
  if (input.subLink && input.subLink.length === 1) {
    return (
      <ul>
        Length is 1
        <LinkChecker props={input.subLink[0]} />
      </ul>
    );
  } else if (input.subLink && input.subLink.length > 1) {
    return <p>Here will be a map</p>;
  } else {
    return <p>Nothing returend at all</p>;
  }
};
```

See attached screenshot showing the structrure of the array I get, I get multiple inputs; the attached screenshots shows one of the incoming array elements with a subLink array length of 1

[image: Screenshot from console showing array structure of input]

Comment: I think it is input[0].subLink and not input.subLink

Comment: `input` is an array and has no property `subLink`. The objects inside the `input` array have that property